# Each row sharey individually?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a two-by-two plot that I am creating dynamically. In the first row I want to plot density functions, in the second row CDFs. I want

- each of the columns to share x
- each of the rows to share y

That is, two objects aligned vertically have the same x-axis, and two plots aligned horizontally have the same y-axis.

However, `sharex` and `sharey` force them to be the same for all of the subplots. How can I fix this sort of axes sharing? I understand that I could be manually giving each axes a share partner, but that wouldn't work with the generic structure that follows:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True)
for i, lam in enumerate(lams):
    axesNow = [axs[i] for axs in axes]  # pick the ith column from axes
    for i, Param.p in enumerate(pp):
        axesNow[0].plot(somethingWithPDF)
        axesNow[1].plot(somethingWithCDF)

for ax in axes.flatten(): ax.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 151):

The [pyplot.subplots documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) describes the `'col'` and `'row'` options for the `sharex` and `sharey` kwargs. In particular, I think you want:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex='col', sharey='row')
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this, where all axes are built individually:

```
x1 = np.arange(5)
y1 = np.arange(3, 8)
ax1 = plt.subplot(223)
ax1.plot(x1, y1)
ax1.set_title("ax1")

x2 = np.arange(5, 10)
y2 = np.arange(3, 8)
ax2 = plt.subplot(224, sharey=ax1)
ax2.plot(x2, y2)
ax2.set_title("ax2")
#plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), visible=False) # Use this to hide axes labels


x3 = x1
y3 = np.arange(13, 8, -1)
ax3 = plt.subplot(221, sharex=ax1)
ax3.plot(x3, y3)
ax3.set_title("ax3")
#plt.setp(ax3.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)


x4 = x2
y4 = y3
ax4 = plt.subplot(222, sharex=ax2, sharey=ax3)
ax4.plot(x4, y4)
ax4.set_title("ax4")
#plt.setp(ax4.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
#plt.setp(ax4.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That works indeed, I was looking for a generic (non-individual) approach

Comment: More code, and much harder to modify than farenorth's answer.